# Use Babel runtime, but only for helpers, not polyfills?

Tags: babeljs

When I I use Babel with the runtime option, it gets its own helper functions like _createClass via imports (instead of just printing these functions inline). I'm happy with this.

But it also replaces any use of Set, Map etc. with its own polyfills, which I don't want because I'm going to Browserify my code and use it in browsers where I've already polyfilled those features where necessary.

Is there a way to configure Babel to use the runtime only for importing internal helpers, and not to polyfill new APIs?

Comment: What is your concern with `Map` and `Set`? `core-js`, Babel's polyfill, will only replace them if it needs to, it doesn't force-replacement always.

Comment: There is https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/external-helpers/ but if you are on Node 4, there is no reason not to load the polyfill. I'm confused about why the duplicated helpers matter anyway though, since it will have a negligible affect on anything if you aren't bundling and sending the JS to a client.

Comment: True, but it's still a waste of resources to load core-js into memory when I know it's not needed, even if it elects to return natives. And what if I wanted to Browserify my code and use it in browsers that support Map and Set natively (or where I know I have already polyfilled them globally)? There needs to be a way to opt out of polyfilling, without also opting out of importing helpers efficiently.

Comment: You're right though. I only used Node 4 as an example, I care about this for browsers too. I've updated my question.

Comment: The external helpers option looks interesting but not quite right. I can't pollute the global environment in my situation. I want it to import helpers as needed, like with the runtime option just without polyfills.

Comment: Then the answer is that it's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `core-js` as a polyfill, then you cannot use `runtime`. The alternative is the load the [external helpers](https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/external-helpers/) which creates a global object that contains all of Babel's helper functions.

In your entry point, do

```
require("babel-core/external-helpers");
```

and pass

```
externalHelpers: true
```

as part of your Babel configuration.